# Java , what is the advantage of declaring a variable of an abstract class type over declaring variable of an subclass type

Tags: java, class, subclass, abstract

Let's say there are two classes, one is an `abstract class Insect` and the other is named `class Beetle extends Insect`.

So when instantiating `Beetle` object in main, you can either use `Insect beetle = new Beetle();` or `Beetle beetle = new Beetle();`.

But if you instantiate using `Insect beetle = new Beetle();`, it requires casting to use the method and variables in child Beetle class, while using `Beetle beetle = new Beetle();` is capable of using all methods and variables both from parent class and `Beetle` class without casting.

So just wondering if there any situations that declaring a variable of an abstract class type has an advantage over declaring a variable of a subclass type?? Because it seems like declaring a variable of a subclass type seems more convenient to use. Thank you in advance^^

Comment: You should also look up "coding to an interface" on Google, it's much the same as an abstract.

Comment: I have found this useful when designing interfaces. In the interface methods I can use abstract/interface types. This allows the design to be open for extension. Typically when you find yourself defining additional public methods in the child class that you intend to use in your application, it is a sign that a redesign/refactor is due.

Comment: Thanks for the link and info, it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

The abstract class if providing some generic behavior implementation to the extending class, in your case Beetle.

But if Beetle has a property which is not common across all insects, and this property is magnifying the insects generic implementation, then you would add it to Beetle. Some other insect implementation, may/may not have class specific property.